# Disabling input boxes with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have some input boxes that I want to disable for a few seconds if one is clicked.

I am using `setTimeout` and `disabled` property to make the check boxes un-clickable. Then I would like to use `clearTimeout` to make it clickable again after moments have passed.

Two issues I'm running into:

1. If I click one box, it only disables the first checkbox. I'm assuming it's because it only disables the first checkbox with the `id='test'` But if I change it to `getElementsByClassName` the `disabled` doesn't work.
2. The `clearTimeout` is just not working.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxpw53ka/8/). You can comment out lines 6-8 in the Javascript section to see how the `disableClick()` function works with an ID, but only disables Digital Filter.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input id="test" type="checkbox" value="digital-filter" onclick="setTimeout(disableClick, 500)">
<span>Digital Filter</span>
<input id="test" type="checkbox" value="meter" onclick="setTimeout(disableClick, 500)">
<span>Meter</span>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var subfilters;
function disableClick(){
    subfilters = document.getElementById("test").disabled = true;
}

setTimeout(() => {
  clearTimeout(subfilters);
}, 250);
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Focus on **one** problem at a time. Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. We can't tell what goes wrong when you use `getElementsByClassName` because we can't see how you are trying to use it.

Comment: The value of ```subfilters``` is true not a timeout id. So calling ```clearTimeout()``` here won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something simpler, without `clearTimeout`.

```js
const tests = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
const form = document.querySelector('.filters')

form.addEventListener('change', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  // you may add this line to disable intputs only when you check
  if (!e.target.checked) return
  
  tests.forEach(test => test.disabled = true)
  setTimeout(() => tests.forEach(test => test.disabled = false), 500)
})
```

```html
<form class='filters'>
  <label>
    <input class="test" type="checkbox" value="digital-filter">
    Digital Filter
  </label>
  <label>
    <input class="test" type="checkbox" value="meter">
    Meter
  </label>
<form>
```

Comment: @j-0n-e-z thank you for your response! That is a much more simpler solution. I like that you used `document.querySelectorAll()` to target all. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do exactly, but [am I close](http://jsfiddle.net/pw8dzvsx/6/)?

```
const options = document.querySelector('.options');
const lockableInputs = options.querySelectorAll('.lockable-input');

options.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const { target } = e;
  
  if (!target.closest('.lockable-input')) return;
  
  e.preventDefault();
  
  if (!target.checked) return;
  
  lockableInputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = true);

  setTimeout(() => {
    lockableInputs.forEach(input => input.disabled = false);
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response! That is exactly what I wanted to achieve. I'll be giving the answer to j-0-n-e-z as it is less code. But thank you, you are a genius :)

Comment: Just keep in mind @Ruby that the answer from @j-0-n-e-z is less code, but it breaks a few rules. First, you should never use the same ID twice - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id#:~:text=The%20id%20global%20attribute%20defines%20an%20identifier%20(ID)%20which%20must%20be%20unique%20in%20the%20whole%20document.). Second, you shouldn't use inline `onclick` handlers - use `addEventListener` and a delegate instead, where possible (this allows for dynamically added checkboxes). Third, this disables inputs even when *unchecked*. Have fun!